# ffmpeg Option not found `var_stream_map a:0 a:1`

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I am using fluent ffmpeg with ffmpeg v4.1.3 for HLS mukti bitrate streaming but I m not able to use -var_stream_map config it says option, not found but running this command outside fluent-ffmpeg works fine

Here is my code

```
    const stream = ffmpeg(filePath);
        stream.outputOptions([
            '-preset slow',
            '-g 48',
            '-map 0:0',
            '-q:a:0 64k',
            '-q:a:1 128k',
            '-var_stream_map a:0 a:1',
            '-hls_time 6',
            '-f hls',
            '-hls_list_size 0',
            '-master_pl_name /tmp/master.m3u8',
            "-hls_segment_filename /tmp/v%v/fileSequence%d.t",
            "/tmp/v%v/prog_index.m3u8"
        ])
        .output('./master.m3u8')
        .on('progress', function(progress) {
            console.log('Processing: ' + progress.percent + '% done')
        })
```

Here is the output

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.3-tessus  https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.3)
  configuration: --cc=/usr/bin/clang --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --extra-version=tessus --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-version3 --pkg-config-flags=--static --disable-ffplay
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Unrecognized option 'var_stream_map a:0 a:1'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

Can someone tell me how can I pass it correctly?

Answer (score 2):

I also face the same problem and solve that by putting the 'var_stream_map' in another outputOption().

```
stream.outputOptions([
            '-preset slow',
            '-g 48',
            '-map 0:v', '-map 0:v',
            '-map 0:a', '-map 0:a',
            '-q:a:0 64k',
            '-q:a:1 128k',
            '-hls_time 6',
            '-f hls',
            '-hls_list_size 0',
            '-master_pl_name /tmp/master.m3u8',
            "-hls_segment_filename /tmp/v%v/fileSequence%d.t",
            "/tmp/v%v/prog_index.m3u8"
        ])
        .outputOption('-var_stream_map', 'v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1')
        .output('./master.m3u8')
        .on('progress', function(progress) {
            console.log('Processing: ' + progress.percent + '% done')
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

On command line it is recommended put the `var_stream_map` value between quotation marks.

```
'-var_stream_map', '"a:0 a:1"'
```

Also the `-map` parameter adds only one stream (stream `0:0`). If you want to have two audio streams you must also add the `-map` parameter two times:

```
-map 0:0 -map 0:0
```

Here the same input stream `0:0` is added two times for the output processing.